# Visual Studio 2010 and HTML5

Tags: visual-studio-2010, html5, validation

I have a couple of questions regarding VS2010 and HTML5:

1. Is there a way to have validation for HTML5 in Visual Studio 2010?

   [image]
2. How can I have the nice "block" to collapse and uncollapse on new the Html5 tags?

   [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682180/will-visual-studio-2010-support-html-5

---

> HTML 5 intellisense and validation schema for Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Web Developer is for [downloading](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2009/11/18/html-5-intellisense-and-validation-schema-for-visual-studio-2008-and-visual-web-developer.aspx). Follow the instructions posted on the page to install the new scheme. Seems like the Visual Studio Team will be supporting HTML 5 after all.

---

> How can you support something that doesn't exist? Something you can't validate against because there's no accepted spec?
>
> Yes they could build in support for the experimental DTD, but they did that with XML/XSLT/XPath and ended up fragmenting XML support for far too long and were attacked for it from all sides.